# create folder using outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using a vba code in outlook to get some text from an email and use this text to create a windows folder in a directory.

The code pickups the text after `Company Name:` from an email body and should then create the folder with whatever text appears after `company name:`

So if we had Company Name: Fred Burts

Then Fred Burts should become our new folder name.

For some reason the error appears to be on my string `LResult336` as when I replace this with text it works fine.

Can someone explain why I am getting the error bad file name? I am using LResult336 as a string which contains the text I want as my folder name.

```
Dim FSO As Object

Dim FolderPath As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
 Dim b4 As String
 Dim strNewFolderName As String

 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b4 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb As Integer
        indexOfNameb = InStr(UCase(b4), UCase("Company name: "))


    Dim indexOfNamec As Integer
       indexOfNamec = InStr(UCase(b4), UCase("Company number: "))

    Dim finalStringb As String

        finalStringb = Mid(b4, indexOfNameb, indexOfNamec - indexOfNameb)

        LResult336 = Replace(finalStringb, "Company Name: ", "")

    FolderPath = "\\uksh000-file06\purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & LResult336
    If FSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) = False Then
    Dim strDir As String
    strDir = "\\uksh000-file06\purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & LResult336
    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir strDir
    Else
    MsgBox "Directory exists."
    End If

    Else

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you should see there is a line feed after the name.

```
LResult336 = Replace(finalStringb, "Company Name: ", "")
Debug.Print "*" & LResult336 & "*"
```

This should work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Outlook2007ProgrammingCh17_ParsingTextFromAMessageBody

```
LResult336 = ParseTextLinePair(b4, "Company Name: ")
Debug.Print "*" & LResult336 & "*"

Function ParseTextLinePair _
  (strSource As String, strLabel As String)
    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
        If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            intLocLabel = _
              Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function
```